# atoi only returning first digit of char* parameter

Tags: c++, c, atoi

When running my program with parameter 15, atoi returns 1.  Atoi only returns the first digit.  Is this supposed to happen?  How to I get around it?

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that `atoi` returned 1?

Comment: by breaking after that line and looking at the value in a

Comment: That won't work. Since `a` is local and never accessed, the compiler has no reason to actually write the result to `a`.

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting.  declaring on a separate line doesn't fix the issue.  That 1 is most certainly being written to a.  printing a prints 1.  printing `atoi(argv[1])` prints 1

Comment: Why not have it print the value of `a`? You need to make the value of `a` part of your program's observable behavior. Using a debugger to make behavior observable is unreliable. Using a debugger to analyze observable behavior is fairly reliable. Actually observing behavior is reliable. You've picked the worst way to make this determination.

Comment: @user2081737 Why don't you add `printf( "%d\n", a ) ;` or `std::cout << a << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

It should convert the entire NUL-terminated string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << atoi("15");
}
```

result:

```
15
```

Comment: that worked properly.  It seems my argv is being weird.. It was doing this before using the computers at this library but I don't remember how I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from _tmain to main fixed the issue.

Comment: If you use `_tmain` you should also use `TCHAR` instead of char and `_ttoi` instead of `atoi`